# Apache Ignite - What protocol does thick client use to join cluster

Tags: ignite

We have Apache Ignite cluster in a Private Network. And trying to load data from different network using thick client, but thick client is not able to join the cluster.

What permission should we check ?

Able to connect using thin client but, I need thick client.

Answer (score 1):

That setup is not recommended, but you should be able to get it working using [forceClientToServerConnections](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/clustering/running-client-nodes-behind-nat) mode.

The preferred way would be to use a thin client. It's worth noting that its feature set is almost equal to a thick one nowadays.

Comment: Tried `forceClientToServerConnections`, but did not work.

Comment: Likely it's something else, like not forwarded ports or something. Hard to tell without the logs. But  I can confirm that having forceClientToServerConnections enabled, a server in AWS and a thick client on a local machine, does work.